# Why do I get differing legends in ggplot while world mapping?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rworldmap

I am trying to plot the following DFs with ggplot2 and maps. I have no issue in the plot itself, yet the two legends look different. I tried different combinations, with breaks, setting limits, still the two differs. What I need is the legends for the two plots to be the same, with values having the same colours.

I tried the following. But the two legends do not match. IN the plot of DF2 this seem to work for me, but in DF1 the legends starts from 100, and colours do not match. Can someone point me to a practical solution?

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(data = DF1, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = V1), col="black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(20)),guide="colourbar",
 breaks = c(1,100, 1000, 10000,100000, 1000000),
trans = "log10")
                        +
  ggtitle("Title(log10)")

**-Plot DF2**


ggplot(data = DF2, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = V2), col="black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(20)),guide="colourbar",
 breaks = c(1,100, 1000, 10000,100000, 1000000),
trans = "log10")
                        +
  ggtitle("TitleDF2(log10)")
```

My Data:

```
DF1
structure(list(long = c(55.1921882629395, 55.1940422058105, 55.1858367919922, 
55.1194343566895, 55.1042976379395, 55.0250015258789, 54.9982452392578, 
54.9224586486816, 54.8048820495605, 54.6522483825684, 54.4716796875, 
54.2701187133789, 54.0545883178711, 53.8321304321289, 53.6095695495605, 
53.39404296875, 53.1923828125, 53.0119132995605, 52.8592796325684, 
52.7416000366211, 52.6659202575684), lat = c(22.9229507446289, 
22.8500003814697, 22.7041015625, 22.6239261627197, 22.6214847564697, 
22.6311531066895, 22.6343746185303, 22.6436538696289, 22.6580085754395, 
22.6766605377197, 22.69873046875, 22.7233390808105, 22.7496585845947, 
22.7768058776855, 22.8040046691895, 22.830322265625, 22.8549308776855, 
22.8770008087158, 22.8956050872803, 22.9100093841553, 22.9192867279053
), group = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15), order = 1049:1069, region = c("United Arab Emirates", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates"), subregion = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), V1 = c(12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 
12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 
12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 
12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 
12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 
12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578, 12905.6580666578)), row.names = 1010:1030, class = "data.frame")


DF2:
structure(list(long = c(-64.3834457397461, -64.6214828491211, 
-64.8529815673828, -64.8198776245117, -64.8043899536133, -64.8694839477539, 
-64.9169006347656, -65.0694351196289, -65.1333999633789, -65.15185546875, 
-65.1549758911133, -65.1278839111328, -65.0182647705078, -65.0070266723633, 
-65.05908203125, -64.9863739013672, -64.8980484008789, -64.6995162963867, 
-64.6224594116211, -64.5377502441406, -64.51171875), lat = c(-40.9224586486816, 
-40.8544921875, -40.8137664794922, -40.7932586669922, -40.7565460205078, 
-40.73583984375, -40.7313499450684, -40.8052749633789, -40.8806648254395, 
-40.9469757080078, -41.1056632995605, -41.23876953125, -41.56689453125, 
-41.7451171875, -41.9699211120605, -42.10205078125, -42.1618156433105, 
-42.2208023071289, -42.2610321044922, -42.2545890808105, -42.2702140808105
), group = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), order = 1554:1574, region = c("Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina"
), subregion = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), V2 = c(5830.59840429215, 
5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 
5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 
5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 
5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 
5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215, 5830.59840429215
)), row.names = 1500:1520, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest option in order to create the same look is to use facet graphs - you will have a joined legend for both plots.

I have removed the trans argument in scale_... I would probably recommend against using it. In order to show log transformed data, the safer option is to log transform your data first, and then plot it. You can then set the breaks according to your log values (in this case 1:6 is equivalent to 10, 100, 1000, etc). I have included an option to do this in ggplot directly. I have slightly changed the values in DF2 in order to make the effect a bit clearer.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

DF2$V2 <- DF2$V2/10 #just to make the difference more obvious

p1 <- 
  ggplot(data = DF1, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = log10(V1)), col="black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(20)),guide="colourbar",
                       breaks = c(1:6),
                       limits = c(1,6)) +
  ggtitle("Title(log10)")

p2 <- 
  ggplot(data = DF2, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = log10(V2)), col="black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(20)),guide="colourbar",
                       breaks = c(1:6),
                       limits = c(1,6)) +
  ggtitle("TitleDF2(log10)")

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. But it is supposed to be a world map (and not  where each country has a different color depending on the value associated to it.  The two dataframes (DF1 and DF2) indicate different stuff I want to highlight. I don´t understand how this is supposed to help me out? can you please further describe your approach?

Comment: @AjejjeBrazov23 fill aesthetic behaves the same for polygons and bars. It does not matter if you draw a map or bars - It's the same in principle, for the problem in question. You did not provide a reproducible question, so I reduced your question to the core of the problem - the mapping of the fill to values. If this does not answer your question, please kindly rephrase your question, and also provide enough data to reproduce your problem fully.

Comment: Thank you. I have now included the two DFs I am using to plot the two DFs. Does this help?
BAck to your reply. The two DFs are not to be combined as their variables differ. I tried your approach but it does not work for me.